# how to use the InMemoryRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to load images from a server asynchronously in window phone using the code below but the InMemoryRandomAccessStream  brings the error

**"The type or namespace name 'InMemoryRandomAccessStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

```
private async Task GetImageTaskAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1080606601222&id=e7d54ea3862e939e6fd414b8750d86bdimage/jpeg1601204364");

        byte[] img = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));

        writer.WriteBytes(img);

        await writer.StoreAsync();

        BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();

        b.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
    }
```

my using statements are as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using RaveCompass.Resources;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

Kindly assist, and if there other ways i can load images from a website as asynchronously, kindly suggest

Comment: Did you reference the correct assembly in the project file?

Comment: @acfrancis I thinks so, Its the Windows.Storage.Streams ;

Answer (score 1):

`InMemoryRandomAccessStream` is not available for Windows Phone, it's for Windows 8 only. Check out on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream).

You don't need `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` to set image via URL `BitmapImage`. You can set URL itself as source.

```
private void GetImageTaskAsync()
{
    BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1080606601222&id=e7d54ea3862e939e6fd414b8750d86bdimage/jpeg1601204364"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that Windows Phone 7 use a "WP edition" of Silverlight, so:

1. the download for the BitmapImage is an asynchronous operation
2. by default Silverlight tries to delay downloading or rendering things until necessary
3. Silverlight won't render the Image until it has been added to the visual tree, i.e. when it is about to be displayed.

Please follow the info available at [Loading an http-image into WriteableImage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/e823c857-f962-46af-a2f8-d7c6ea593ece/loading-an-httpimage-into-writeableimage?forum=wpdevelop). I know is less elegant than using await, but I didn't find any other way to do it.

If someone know a better way, possibly using the async await pattern, please let us know.